# How to go back to previous uncomitted state after git pull

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a `feature-branch` alongside with my colleague. It's been a few days that I that have `committed` my changes.

Yesterday he has committed his changes and that changed the structure of the project we were working on but didn't harm my changes.

I have pulled those changes and made a commit with mine.Upon testing later I realized its not working the way I want it to be, so I want to go back to the state before that pull.

I cannot go back to my previous commit since by doing that my latest changes will be lost.

I tried `git reflog` which show me this output :

```
08aed28 HEAD@{0}: commit: Added support for database
4cf0fe8 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
d5e2930 HEAD@{2}: commit: Added logs
```

I did `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` but that will not take me to previous state.

What should I do ?

Comment: You could go back to your old commit, preferably create a branch, and [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your "new" commit onto the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

To continue working with your changes on a older commit I would suggest you the following chain of commands - I'll assume you are using the command line interface.

1. Find the commit you want to "start" work from (let's say the commit hash is `123abc`)
2. Create a branch which points to that commit (let's call it `test`) - `git branch test 123abc`
3. Check the new branch out - `git checkout test`
   (You can combine this two steps by using `git checkout -b test 123abc`)
4. Use [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to regain your new changes

**cherry-pick** ([documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))

You can use `cherry-pick` to (quote documentation) "*Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits*".

In your case you could now simply use a command similar to this one: `git cherry-pick 456def` (where `456def` is the hash of the commit whose changes you want to apply).

It's also possible to `cherry-pick` a range of commits, if you for example want to pick the latest 3 commits from the master branch your command could look like this `git cherry-pick master~3..`.

For further information on take a look at the [`gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) documentation or alternativly the [Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) chapter of the [progit book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).